# WiFi Direct connection: Android on Nexus 5

Tags: android, wifi-direct, nexus-5

people, 
i have a problem.
I'm traying to connect two Nexus 5 devices from LG unsing WiFi Direct, but I have problems.
I have studied this manual
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html
but it doesnt works properly.

The first problem is the peers discovery. One device is located near the other device. Than I start the peers discovery and the devices can not always find each other.
And even if they find each other, And even if they have found themselves. In a short time they lose again.

And even if it is done correctly than I can not got the connection beetween the devices.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but the sample App 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo
is working not properly too.

Have only Nexus 5 problems of this kind,
or have the code of android-OS bugs,
or maybe somethink else?

Are there any devices where WiFiDirect is stable working?

Thank you for the answers 
and ssory for my bad english.

Comment: It is unclear what you are doing. If you want two devices to connect by wifi direct then the user(s) of the devices go into settings and do the needed things. After that the devices are connected. Are programming an app? What should that app do?

Comment: I'm traying to programm a application. Two devices have this application running and than the devices must connect to each other through WiFi-Direct and exchange massages.

And to programm this application a have tryed this manual:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

But the code is not doing that, what I want properly.

Comment: If I call the discoverPeers method after initialization, than the BroadcastReceiver must receive soon the Intent with the action equals to WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION. But it doesnot work every time.

Very offten the discoverPeers-Method-call doesnot find the other device which is very close.

Comment: If I try to find the second nexus 5 devices in the wifi-direct-settings. (Settings -> wifi -> wifidirect -> search peers) it douesnt works every time. The quastion is, what can I do? Maybe I can bay two other devices from other firma or I must wait of new version of android, where this bug is fixed.

Comment: Well if the nexus 5 cannot establish a reliable wifi direct connection itself then there is little you can do. Bring them back to the shop? You could google for this being a know bug. Meanwhile buy some cheap chinese phones and continue programming ;-).

Comment: >Meanwhile buy some cheap chinese phones

Comment: Maybe this is a problem off all phones because wifi-Direct is new and still not sophisticated

Comment: Did you google already?

Comment: Yes I googled already. 
There are some comments about troubles with wifi-direct on nexus. F.e.:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/fc1FJKw2Jt8/lAPm61uER5MJ